# How to set minimum x-axis interval in iOS chart?

Tags: ios, ios-charts

How do I set the minimum x-axis (horizontal line). In the example below it has 7 lines. How do I make it to have only 4 intervals?

Also, is there a way to remove the circle on every point to make it just plain line?

For reference, I'm using the [iOS-Charts library](https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts)

[image: example graph]

Comment: For clarification, is this the library you're using: https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts?

Comment: yes the same library I am using

Comment: @SandeshSardarHave you got the solution for this? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show only 4 intervals then you can set the label count to 4.

```
 chartView.xAxis.labelCount = 4
```

To hide the circle, disable the drawCircleEnabled for ChratDataSet

```
chartDataSet.drawCirclesEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the minimum of the axis you need to set the `customAxisMin` property of the axis.

For example in swift:

```
lineChartView.leftAxis.customAxisMin = 0
```

To remove the circle you have to set the `drawCirclesEnabled` property to `false` on your `LineChartDataSet`

Comment: lineChartView.leftAxis.customAxisMin = 0
 is for y-axis, but I need for x-axis

Answer (score 0):

For the dot, disable `dataSet.isDrawCirclesEnabled`.

For the range, check below out. BTW, you have to understand that because you have 7 x axis values, it will draw every one of it by default. If you want fine-grained control, you need to change the renderer logic.

You can set the max range is 4, so only 4 x axis values will be displayed, otherwise you should only pass 4 data values into the chart.

```
/// Sets the size of the area (range on the x-axis) that should be maximum visible at once (no further zomming out allowed).
/// If this is e.g. set to 10, no more than 10 values on the x-axis can be viewed at once without scrolling.
public func setVisibleXRangeMaximum(maxXRange: CGFloat)
{
    let xScale = _deltaX / maxXRange
    _viewPortHandler.setMinimumScaleX(xScale)
}

/// Sets the size of the area (range on the x-axis) that should be minimum visible at once (no further zooming in allowed).
/// If this is e.g. set to 10, no less than 10 values on the x-axis can be viewed at once without scrolling.
public func setVisibleXRangeMinimum(minXRange: CGFloat)
{
    let xScale = _deltaX / minXRange
    _viewPortHandler.setMaximumScaleX(xScale)
}
```